# Using getstream.io chat with Angular 11/12

Tags: angular, getstream-io

I'm trying to use getstream.io with Angular 11/12.

Step 1: installed npm via npm install getstream

Step 2: installed additional dependencies via npm install express @types/node and added `"types": ["node"]` to tsconfig

Step 3: simple init service to initialize StreamChat:

```js
import { StreamChat } from "stream-chat";

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class ChatService {
  client: StreamChat;

  constructor() {
    this.client = StreamChat.getInstance(environment.getstream.apiKey);
  }

  async connectUserChat() {
    await this.client.connectUser(
      {
        id: 'xxx',
        name: 'Some Testuser'
      },
      "xxx",
    );
  }
}
```

Result:

```
Error: node_modules/stream-chat/dist/types/client.d.ts:3:8 - error TS1259: Module '"xxx/node_modules/isomorphic-ws/index"' can only be default-imported using the 'allowSyntheticDefaultImports' flag

3 import WebSocket from 'isomorphic-ws';
         ~~~~~~~~~

  node_modules/isomorphic-ws/index.d.ts:8:1
    8 export = WebSocket
      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    This module is declared with using 'export =', and can only be used with a default import when using the 'allowSynth
eticDefaultImports' flag.


Error: node_modules/stream-chat/dist/types/connection.d.ts:3:8 - error TS1259: Module '"xxx/node_modules/isomorphic-ws/index"' can only be default-imported using the 'allowSyntheticDefaultImports' flag

3 import WebSocket from 'isomorphic-ws';
         ~~~~~~~~~

  node_modules/isomorphic-ws/index.d.ts:8:1
    8 export = WebSocket
      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    This module is declared with using 'export =', and can only be used with a default import when using the 'allowSynth
eticDefaultImports' flag.


Error: node_modules/stream-chat/dist/types/utils.d.ts:2:8 - error TS1259: Module '"xxx-
web/node_modules/stream-chat/node_modules/form-data/index"' can only be default-imported using the 'allowSyntheticDefaul
tImports' flag

2 import FormData from 'form-data';
         ~~~~~~~~

  node_modules/stream-chat/node_modules/form-data/index.d.ts:10:1
    10 export = FormData;
       ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    This module is declared with using 'export =', and can only be used with a default import when using the 'allowSynth
eticDefaultImports' flag.
```

Any idea how to get this fixed?

I'm also a bit puzzled if the getstream lib actually works with Angular at all. I can find some official tutorial using Angular 9, but I can't find anything in their docs regarding Angular support.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

adding `"esModuleInterop": true` to tsconfig.json removed the errors for now

Answer (score 0):

adding in tsconfig.json

```
"compilerOptions": {
 "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
}
```